# How to change WordPress Plugin Text English to French

Tags: wordpress

I am using the WPML Plugin, Complete site is translated well. But I am getting one issue in BMI calculator plugin. I want to change the text like height, width text. Through WPML Plugin, Its not going to work. Please check the site below
http://www.cmna-mtl.ca/fr/calculate-your-bmi/

Comment: you have to change the language for the page from BMI calculator plugin's files.

Comment: Thanks, Can you provide any hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the code into **bmi-calculator-shortcode >> bmi-calculator-shortcode.php file**

Try this code,

**Now, check the line number 41**

```html
public function processShortcode($attrs) {
  
  if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'):
   $metricText = $attrs['metric'] ?: 'Metric';
   $imperialText = $attrs['imperial'] ?: 'Imperial';
   $heightText = $attrs['height'] ?: 'Height';
   $weightText = $attrs['weight'] ?: 'Weight';
   $heightPlaceholder = $attrs['heightPlaceholder'] ?: 'Height';
   $weightPlaceholder = $attrs['weightPlaceholder'] ?: 'Weight';
   $submitText = $attrs['submit'] ?: 'Submit';
   $theme = $attrs['theme'] ?: 'default';
   $resultText = $attrs['result'] ?: 'Your BMI is %bmi%';
    $resultText = str_replace('%bmi%', '<span class="bmi-number"></span>', $resultText);
    
  elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr'):
   
   $metricText = $attrs['metric'] ?: 'Métrique';
   $imperialText = $attrs['imperial'] ?: 'Impérial';
   $heightText = $attrs['height'] ?: 'la taille';
   $weightText = $attrs['weight'] ?: 'Poids';
   $heightPlaceholder = $attrs['heightPlaceholder'] ?: 'la taille';
   $weightPlaceholder = $attrs['weightPlaceholder'] ?: 'Poids';
   $submitText = $attrs['submit'] ?: 'Soumettre';
   $theme = $attrs['theme'] ?: 'default';
   $resultText = $attrs['result'] ?: 'Votre IMC est %bmi%';
    $resultText = str_replace('%bmi%', '<span class="bmi-number"></span>', $resultText);
    
  endif;
```

For your code understanding, share this code in below

```html
<?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
    <!-- english here -->
<?php elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
    <!-- spanish here -->
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- ======== Or ======= -->
<?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
    <!-- english here -->
<?php else: ?>
    <!-- spanish here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: One more question, I am not the developer but want to be in wordpress and php, So could you please guide me ? How to start ?

Comment: How to start from like basics ? Any pdf or Online classes ?

Comment: thanks... !!! means you have to learn wordpress basics. so, you can go through this link -  https://codex.wordpress.org/

Comment: My website: http://www.igeniee.com/company
http://www.igeniee.com/company
After signup, I need to create a sub doamin Example: xyz/igeniee.com
I am using the purchased theme. 

Priyanka mam can you help?

Answer (score 0):

**WPML** provides string translation by default and it recognize string from file if found in following manner:

```
 $metricText = $attrs['metric'] ?: __('Metric', 'default');
```

Do all your text like above and upload your file.

Now go to **WP-Admin -> WPML -> String Translation**

Search your string **Metric** and do translate. Simple and easy.

It may 1-2 minutes to take effect to come in search so wait for 1-2 minutes and search your text.